# Low rank approximation with random gaussian projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, normal-distribution

Let's say we have a matrix A which is $m\times n$ matrix and $n \gg m$. We multiply A with a random gaussian matrix G with $0$ mean and $I$ variance and dimension $n \times (k+p)$ where $p$ is an oversampling parameter and $k$ is the desired rank and $(k+p) < m$. Let $Y = AG$. When we do QR factorization on $Y$ and get the column subspace $Q$, the $\| A - QQ^TA\|$ is probabilistically bounded ([ref](https://candes.su.domains/publications/downloads/RandomizedNLA.pdf)).

My problem is following: instead of multiplying $A$ with a highly low-ranked matrix (lower than m), we multiply it with an $n\times t$ Gaussian matrix where  $t \geq m$. Then apply SVD on $Y$: $\mbox{SVD}(Y) = U \Sigma V^T$. Then use $U[:,k]$ for low rank approximation. Is there any bound for $\| A - U[:,k]U[:,k]^TA\|$? Experimentally, the results are much better but could not find an exact proof for this algorithm.

Comment: "My problem is following: instead of multiplying $A$ with a highly low-ranked matrix, we multiply it with an $n\times t$ Gaussian matrix where  $t \geq m$": is this supposed to be different from you you describe in the first paragraph?

Comment: Yes, actually it is. In the first case, (k+p) < m. Forgot to add. Sorry for the inconvenience.